# dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick não funciona!

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, eventos

estou com a função mais simples do mundo e não consigo fazer a mesma funcionar.
Ao dar 2 cliques em qualquer célula de meu datagridview quero que exiba a mensagem "1", mas não está funcionando! O que tem de errado?

Vejam meu código:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("1");
    }

    public static void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1");
    }
```

Comment: Se você clicar em cima do valor contido na célula, o resultado será nulo porque a mensagem está comentada, mas se você clicar na célula depois do conteúdo, será chamada a segunda função e o resultado será o esperado.

Answer (score 4):

Sua resposta resolve o "problema", mas não esclarece nada. Para fins de conhecimento, vou tentar te explicar o que acontece bem resumidamente (bom, ficou um pouco mais longo do que eu imaginei).

Quando você cria um form pelo Visual Studio, em **`add -> new form`**, duas classes são geradas no seu projeto.

Supondo que você tenha criado um form chamado **Form1**. Serão criados dois arquivos: **`Form1.cs`** e **`Form1.Designer.cs`**. O "segredo" de tudo, está neste segundo arquivo.

Note que os dois arquivos declaram a **mesma classe** e ambos têm a palavra reservada `partial` em suas assinaturas . Veja no exemplo:

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 { /*O resto do código é irrelevante agora*/ }
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 { /*O resto do código é irrelevante agora*/ }
```

Isso indica que os dois arquivos "se complementam", ou seja, **é a mesma classe** dividida em dois arquivos diferentes. Inclusive, você pode dividir a classe em quantos arquivos quiser. Isso serve pra manter o código mais organizado, tornando possível a separação de algumas responsabilidades.

#### Ok, mas o que isso tem a ver com a pergunta?

O Visual Studio faz essa separação para manter todo o código de criação, posicionamento e definição de propriedades/eventos separados do código que você vai escrever. Assim além de ficar mais organizado e você não precisar escrever seu código no meio daquele monte de código de manipulação de controles, o Visual Studio pode reescrever o arquivo sempre que precisar, sem medo de estragar o código já escrito por você.

Note que no construtor da classe (no arquivo **`Form1.cs`**) é chamado o método `InitializeComponent`, este método está definido no outro arquivo (**`Form1.Designer.cs`**) e ele é o responsável por criar e manipular todos os controles no form.

Isso quer dizer que tudo o que você criar usando o editor visual do Visual Studio, será replicado em forma de código para este arquivo e isto inclui criação de eventos (o que acontece quando é dado um duplo clique num componente ou, como no seu caso, ao clicar na aba de eventos e escolher um deles).

Quando você cria um evento, qualquer que seja, o Visual Studio cria um método no arquivo principal  (**`Form1.cs`**), seguindo seu exemplo:

```
public static void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}
```

e no arquivo **`Form1.Designer.cs`**, este evento é inscrito no componente, desta forma

```
dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
```

Então, você pode criar um evento "na mão", só não pode esquercer de inscrevê-lo no componente. Isso é feito pelo último bloco de código que mostrei, é a sintaxe é basicamente a seguinte:

```
controle.NomeDoEvento += new System.EventHandler(nomeDoMetodoQueVaiSerDisparado);
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido!
Descobri o que era!
Coloquei esse código acima "na mão", não poderia ter feito isso.
Apaguei toda essa linha abaixo:

```
public static void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}
```

Fui no designer, cliquei no DataGridView1, fui em properties, aí cliquei no raiozinho de Events e dei 2 cliques em CellDoubleClick.
Aí sim eu preenchi o MessageBox lá na função que o próprio Visual Studio criou pra mim.