# Definir variável no designer do form

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Como posso definir uma variável no designer de um form?

Hoje eu defino a variável para o meu parâmetro, porem quando vou ver o form ele da esse aviso (mesmo com o aviso, ele executa normalmente):

> The variable 'id_grid' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

Segue o código:

```
this.sqlDataSource1.ConnectionName = "String tpspoazsql01 onee";
this.sqlDataSource1.Name = "sqlDataSource1";
columnExpression15.ColumnName = "nome";
table3.MetaSerializable = "0|0|125|260";
table3.Name = "Cliente_enderecos_alter";
columnExpression15.Table = table3;
column15.Expression = columnExpression15;
columnExpression16.ColumnName = "endereco";
columnExpression16.Table = table3;
column16.Expression = columnExpression16;
columnExpression17.ColumnName = "numero";
columnExpression17.Table = table3;
column17.Expression = columnExpression17;
columnExpression18.ColumnName = "bairro";
columnExpression18.Table = table3;
column18.Expression = columnExpression18;
columnExpression19.ColumnName = "cidade";
columnExpression19.Table = table3;
column19.Expression = columnExpression19;
columnExpression20.ColumnName = "estado";
columnExpression20.Table = table3;
column20.Expression = columnExpression20;
columnExpression21.ColumnName = "cep";
columnExpression21.Table = table3;
column21.Expression = columnExpression21;
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column15);
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column16);
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column17);
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column18);
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column19);
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column20);
selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column21);
selectQuery3.FilterString = "[Cliente_enderecos_alter.id_cliente] = ?ID1";
selectQuery3.Name = "Cliente_enderecos_alter";

queryParameter5.Name = "ID1";
queryParameter5.Type = typeof(int);
queryParameter5.ValueInfo = "0";
```

> ```
>   queryParameter5.Value = id_grid;
> ```

```
selectQuery3.Parameters.Add(queryParameter5);
selectQuery3.Tables.Add(table3);
this.sqlDataSource1.Queries.AddRange(new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlQuery[] {
selectQuery3});
this.sqlDataSource1.ResultSchemaSerializable = resources.GetString("sqlDataSource1.ResultSchemaSerializable");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, você **não deve** mexer no código autogerado pelo Visual Studio (basicamente, no método `InitializeComponent` que está na partial `.Designer`). Se você abrir esta partial vai ver que no *summary* deste método tem o texto abaixo

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
```

Se você colocar seu código neste método tem grande possibilidade de perder o que foi feito quando for mexer no design do form, afinal este arquivo vai ser editado pela IDE.

Fora que, você provavelmente vai quebrar o design do seu form. Por isso o aviso

> The variable 'id_grid' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

Sem mais detalhes sobre o que você está tentando fazer fica difícil de saber, mas eu não consigo ver um real motivo para colocar este código na partial designer. Posso te dar duas dicas para resolver isso:

1. Crie um método na outra partial e chame-o no construtor junto com `InitializeComponent`. Isso não vai separar seu código em outro arquivo, mas já fica bem melhor do que está. Ex.:

   ```
   public Form()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       OutroInicializadorDeComponentes();
   }
   ```
2. Tente criar outro método dentro da partial designer, não tenho certeza que isso irá funcionar, mas acho que sim já que o Visual Studio só coloca aviso para não mexer no método `InitializeComponent`.

---

**Obs.:**

- Você pode ver [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135279/18246) para entender o que é e para que serve uma partial class.

Comment: Amigo boa tarde, obrigado pelas digas. vou estudar suas dicas, eu abri uma pergunta no MSDN e la contem fotos, se puder dar uma olhada, ficaria muito grato. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/b831a788-10e9-4378-a260-f8a9b68ff4d3/gridcontrol-com-where-idcliente-idcliente?forum=vscsharppt

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel acho meio esquisito alguém estando em um site especializado em Q&A tentar levar os usuários para responder suas dúvidas em um fórum.

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel Não vejo motivo para ver sua postagem no MSDN. Eu já respondi aqui...

Comment: Perfeito.Obrigado.

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel lembrando que se tiver outras dúvidas que precisem de imagem, dá pra abrir as perguntas aqui no SOpt e inserir as imagens no post sem problemas. Só é importante observar que se for código, ou mesmo mensagens de erro, você deve por o fonte em texto mesmo, que fica mais fácil de ler, e de copiar e colar para testes e pesquisas. Aqui tem umas [dicas de formatação](/editing-help), e a barra de ferramentas das postagens já tem o ícone de quadrinho para inserção de imagens, e o ícone { } para formatar código. Este texto também tem umas dicas boas para valorizar o texto: [Ask].

Comment: Amigo, boa tarde. perfeito, vou dar uma lida sobre formatação e me atentar quando postar alguma duvida. Obrigado