# Copiei um form e um código de um programa para outro em c# só que não funciona

Tags: c#

O meu programa tava dando erro de diretório, então eu criei outro projeto no Visual Studio, Copiei e colei o form e o código nele, só que o código não corresponde mais ao form, vocês sabem se tem algum problema de referência, ou se o problema é por copiar o form?

Comment: Você copiou o conteúdo ou o arquivo?

Comment: Sim, tem um problema de referência, você deve ter deixado os arquivos `.Designer` pra trás. Veja esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135279/18246

Comment: Bom, se a resposta linkada não responder o seu problema, me avise pelos comentários, mas tenho certeza que é isso.